# Is there any way I can ensure a Windows 8 computer stays on (or switches on at a scheduled time?)

Tags: windows-8, power-supply, windows-task-scheduler

I've got a number of PCs connected to sensors reading data using a program. I can start up the program nice and easily with Task Scheduler and keep it running at all times.

However, it's not in a place with a very consistent power supply, and it can loose power for short periods.

It's a tablet and has an on-board battery - so I get a few hours for the power to turn back on before the computer shuts down. But occasionally it has been for long enough that the battery runs too low and the computer shuts off.

The power turns on a few hours later and the loggers start up - but the computer remains off.

Can I schedule a Windows 8 machine to turn on at a certain time of day, or when it is plugged in (the power switches back on)?

The only solutions Ive been able to find are for automatic shutdown (easy!) and wake-on-LAN, but it's not on a LAN network.

Comment: "However, it's not in a place with a very consistent power supply, and it can loose power for short periods." - Why can't you use a UPS?  Although a few hours, is a long time to be without power, I assume the power situtation can't be resolved?

Comment: It effectively has one, being a tablet, it just potentially doesn't last long enough. Even if I get more battery, its just reducing the risk not getting rid of it. I don't care about it being on all the time when the power is off (sensors don't have power do NP data anyway) and can't afford any additional cost of new hardware.

Comment: Most BIOS/UEFI firmwares do have a schedules on time feature. Mine also has a "Default state on power failure" thats lets you decide whether or not to boot up whenn power is restored. Does your firnware have any of these?